# Create a list in list comprehension and then create another list from that list inside the same list comprehension

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, list-comprehension

That title is a mouthful, so it may be easier to show what I am trying to achieve via code.

```
import pandas as pd

data = []
for i in range(0,6):
    row = []
    for j in range(0,6):
        if i == j:
            row.append(1)
        else:
            row.append(0)
    data.append(row)

colnames = [(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = colnames)
```

The above is not where I am having trouble with, but I wanted to provide as much context as possible.

I am trying to iterate through the dataframe and retrieve the first element of the column name where the dataframe's element equals 1. I can do this using the following:

```
[col[0] for col in df if (df[col] == 1).any()]
```

This generates the first list I need to create:

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I can assign that output to a variable and perform another list comprehension to get my final output:

```
res = [col[0] for col in df if (df[col] == 1).any()]

[(res[i], res[i+1]) for i in range(len(res)-1)]
```

This outputs my final list of:

```
[(1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

Is it possible to perform both of these inside the same list comprehension while only receiving that final list as the output?

This is somewhat inelegant, but this is what it would look like in non-list comprehension:

```
x = []
y = []
for i in range(0,1):
    for col in df:
        if df[col].any() == 1:
            x.append(col[0])
    for j in range(len(x)-1):
        y.append((x[j],x[j+1]))
```

Thank you for taking the time to look this over!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a [`dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) product with a conditional statement , then zip and extract a tuple:

```
[(a,b) for a,b in zip(df.eq(1).dot(df.columns.str[0]),df.eq(1).dot(df.columns.str[0])[1:])]
#same with .iloc -> [(a,b) for a,b in zip(df.eq(1).dot(df.columns.str[0]),df.eq(1).dot(
#                                          df.columns.str[0]).iloc[1:])]
```

---

**Output:**

```
[(1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

**Full Working Code**:

```
data = []
for i in range(0,6):
    row = []
    for j in range(0,6):
        if i == j:
            row.append(1)
        else:
            row.append(0)
    data.append(row)

colnames = [(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = colnames)
[(a,b) for a,b in zip(df.eq(1).dot(df.columns.str[0]),df.eq(1).dot(df.columns.str[0])[1:])]
#[(1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```